# How to force an instant image refresh from an Angular Safeurl without reloading the page

Tags: python, angular, typescript, flask

I've created an angular component (product) on which a user is able to change an image (product's image).

html:

```
<img  [attr.id]="_product.id" [attr.src]="_product.thumbnail_url"/>
```

When the image is chosen by the user from a custom file picker component on a modal form. The following method is called to reload the image in the parent product component.
The *imageBinary* here is a base64 blob binary image returned from a python FLASK REST API endpoint which is connected to a mysql database.

```
  reloadProductImage(new_image_id):void{
    let newUrl:SafeUrl;
    let urlStr:string;
    this.productservice.getImage(new_image_id).subscribe((filedata) =>{
      let imageBinary = filedata.thumbnail; 
      urlStr = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageBinary + '?'+Date.now();
      newUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlStr);
      this.form.patchValue({image_id: new_image_id});
      this._product.thumbnail_url = newUrl;
      this._product.image_id = new_image_id;
```

I've found many examples how to force the browser to a reload on a regular src url by appending a timestamp to the url. However, these examples do not seem to apply to a blob stored in a saferurl.

#### inspect image element

```
<img _ngcontent-snv-c187="" id="146914e3-6e0a-409f-8046-ff04580f6242" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA+++very+long+blob+++vBzu3ZFwwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==?1619156455998">
```

#### Console Error message

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

## Failed attempts

I've tried:

```
newUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageBinary + '?'+ Date.now();
```

and

```
newUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageBinary + '?datetime='+ Date.now();
```

## Background info

For illustration purposes, I'll post my Angular and Python code here (methods in a Flask SQLAlchemy DB Model) which post an image file to a Flask REST API, generate the thumbnail from the base64 image and return it to Angular. Note: the get function is called in a GET request. The Create function is called in a POST request.

### Angular FileUpload component:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {NotificationService} from '../..//notification/notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'fileupload-form',
  template: `
    <p>
      Productfoto toevoegen
    </p>
    <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
    <button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class FileuploadComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile: File = null;

  @Output()
  fileSubmitted = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    ) { }
 
  onFileSelected(event){
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }
  onUpload(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('inputFile', this.selectedFile , this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post(['/offerte/api/files','upload'].join('/'),fd)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.notificationService.success(`Bestand ${this.selectedFile.name} is opgeslagen.`);
        this.fileSubmitted.emit(res);
      })
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

### Python Flask Endpoints:

#### Imports

```
import logging
from io import BytesIO
from flask import request, send_file
from flask_restx import Resource
from api.serializers import fileobject, page_of_files
from api.parsers import pagination_arguments
from api.restplus import api
from database.models import File
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, get_jwt_identity

logger = logging.getLogger()

ns_files = api.namespace('files', description='Operations related to file management')
```

#### POST

```
@ns_files.route('/upload')
class Upload(Resource):
    @api.doc(security='jwt')
    @jwt_required
    def post(self):
        '''Upload a new file, returns id of new file'''
        inputFile = request.files['inputFile']
        logger.info('create new file %s', request.json)
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()

        return File.create(inputFile, current_user)
```

#### GET

```
@ns_files.route('/<string:file_id>')
@api.response(404, 'file not found')
class Details(Resource):
    @api.marshal_with(fileobject)
    def get(self, file_id):
        '''Download a new file from the db (binary storage)'''
        logger.info('loading file %s')
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()
        returnedFile = File.get(file_id)
        return returnedFile
```

### Python FLASK REST API functions

```
from PIL import Image
import magic
from base64 import b64encode
import io

accepted_mime_types = {'jpe':'image/jpeg','jpeg':'image/pjpeg','png':'image/png'}

    def get(id):
        return Product.query.filter(Product.id == id).one()

    def create(inputFile, current_user):
        filename = inputFile.filename
        file_obj = File(
            filename = filename,
            extension = '.jpg', 
            folderpath = 'folderpath', 
            databinary = inputFile.read(), 
            category = 'default',
            description = 'beschrijving...', 
            original_filename = filename,
            created_by = current_user,
            modified_by= current_user)
        MAX_SIZE = (150, 150) 
        thumbnailFile, mimetype = File.getThumbnail(inputFile, MAX_SIZE)
        if not thumbnailFile is None:
            output = io.BytesIO()
            thumbnailFile.save(output, format='PNG')
            hex_data = output.getvalue()
            file_obj.thumbnail = hex_data
        else:
            raise NameError(mimetype)
        db.session.add(file_obj)
        db.session.commit()
        return str(file_obj.id)

    def mimetype(file_obj):
        return magic.from_buffer(file_obj.read(2048), mime=True)

    def getThumbnail(file_obj, size):
        file_obj.seek(0)
        real_mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file_obj.read(2048), mime=True)
        if (real_mime_type in accepted_mime_types.values()):
            thumbnailImage = Image.open(file_obj)
            thumbnailImage.thumbnail(size)
            return thumbnailImage, real_mime_type
        else:
            raise NameError(real_mime_type)
```

Comment: Has you, (in parent) `<fileupload-form (fileSubmitted)="fileSubmited()">`and **in** your fileSubmited function `this.productservice.getThumbnail().subscribe(res=>{....}` to change the imagen?. Remember that a subscription to an httpClient should be **"renoved"** each time you change in the server the data. NOTE: I think that it's not necessary add a "dateTime" nor "time"

Comment: Hi @Eliseo thanks for your comment. the fileSubmitted event emitter informs the parent component (the product) to request the new image using the described reloadProductImage function. So actually each time a user uploads the new image, the subscription is called